# Changes in inplace plugin code in grails3.x are not reloading automatically

Tags: grails, grails-3.0, grails-3.1

I am upgrading a project from Grails 2.5.1 to Grails 3.1.4.

My Multi-Project Build structure in Grails 3.1.4 is as follows:

`- Root
   |--MainProject
   |--Plugin1ForMain
   |--Plugin2ForMain
   |--settings.gradle`

I run the `MainProject` using `grails run-app` command and whenever I change my codes in `Plugin1ForMain` or any other plugins, the changes are not automatically recompiled like it did in Grails2.x .

How can I make my project autocompile plugin's code in grails3.x ? I am using gradle version 2.3

Comment: Try using the latest 3.1.6, there were plugin reloaded fixes between 3.1.4 and 3.1.6.

Comment: didn't work in 3.1.6 either. Tried for [TestApplication](https://github.com/girisagar46/Grails3ReloadTest). I've also created an [Issue](https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/9921).

Answer (score 0):

I also got the same issue with grails 3.1.4 and when I changed the version of Gradle and profile web plugin it started working for me. Hope it solves your problem too.

a) Use Gradle version 2.13, change the Gradle version in gradle.properties

```
gradleWrapperVersion=2.13
```

b) And change the profile plugin version to 3.1.6 in build.gradle

```
profile "org.grails.profiles:web-plugin:3.1.6"
```